# Best performance approach to find all combinations of numbers from a given set(>80 elements) to reach a given final sum

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, combinations

Before I am directed to go and keep searching instead of asking this general question, please understand my question in detail. 
We have the algorithm that does it in pl sql. however it is not performing well when the set of numbers given has large number of elements. for example it works well when the set has around 22 elements. However after that the performance dies. 
We are working with oracle database 12c and this combination of number searching is part of one of our applications and is pulled from oracle tables into associative arrays for finding combinations. example final sum required = 30 
set of elements to choose from {1,2,4,6,7,2,8,10,5} and so forth.

My question in gist :
Is pl sql realistically suited to write such algo ? Should we be looking at another programming language/ technology/ server capacity/ tool to handle larger set of more than 80 elements ?

Comment: If you can come up with a way to partition your data into N groups, where N is the number of cores on your system, you might be able to use a language which supports multithreading to improve the runtime of your code. For example, if you can split your data up into four subsets and process each subset in a separate thread, then a quad-core processor *might* let you get done "fast enough". PL/SQL does not support multithreading. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle is not suitable for solving this problem because databases are not suited for it.  In fact, I think this problem is an NP-complete problem, so there are no truly efficient solutions.

The approach in a database is to generate all possible combinations up to a certain size, and then filter down to the ones that match your sum.  This is inherently an exponential algorithm.  There may be some heuristic algorithms that come close to solving the problem, but this is an inherently hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can find some special condition to shrink the problem you will never solve it.  Don't worry about the language implementation until you know this problem is even theoretically possible.

As others have mentioned, this problem grows exponentially.  Solving it for 22 elements is not even *close* to solving it for 80.

A [dynamic programming algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/) may be able to quickly find if there is *one* solution to a subset sum problem.  But finding all solutions requires testing 2^80 sets.

2^80 = 1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176.  That's 1.2e24.

That's a big number.  Let's make a wildly optimistic assumption that a processor can test one billion sets a second.  Buy a million of them and you can find your answer in about 38 years.  Maybe a quantum computer can solve it more quickly some day.

It might help to explain exactly what you're trying to do.  Unless there is some special condition, some way to eliminate most of the processing and avoid a brute-force solution, I don't see any hope for solving this problem.  Perhaps this is a question for the [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) site.